# Unable to redirect to error page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, handleerror

I tried to redirect to error page on error. but it does not work.

It just giving - `Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500` message on browser instead of redirecting to error page. error page is already existed in shared folder.

Below is the code in controller:

```
  [HandleError(View = "Error")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int u = Convert.ToInt32("");// Error line
        return View();
    }
```

web config has included below line:

```
      <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"></customErrors>
```

did google but, it shows above stuff and it should work but still not work.

Using MVC 4 basic template.

Please guide.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work" ?

Comment: updated question to include that details.

Comment: @phantom yes, it gives an error but not redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Errors can occur in the error view itself. In that case, the default ASP.NET error page is displayed. To avoid this, you can configure the application to display an error file in the `customErrors` section of the `Web.config` file, as shown in the following example:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error.htm" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: How can we achieve using MVC attribute ?

Comment: @Dhaval sure, just decorate the class with the attribute